# Java REST Elastic search: Nested Field mapping using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, objectmapper, elasticsearch-mapping

I have a `field`, for example, `Object_IDs` which can have multiple `Object_ID`. Below is the snippet:

```
"Object_IDs":{  
           "type":"nested",
           "properties":{  
              "Object_ID": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
```

I am using `Elastic search`  `6.2.3` and I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` for mapping objects.

I am not able to create a `nested field` using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. Here is the code snippet:

```
    ObjectNode nestedNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    nestedNode.put("type", "nested");
    nestedNode.put("index", true);
    mapperNode.set("Object_IDs", nestedNode);

    ObjectNode setkeyWord = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    setkeyWord.put("type", "keyword");
    setkeyWord.put("index", true);

    ObjectNode innerProperties = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    innerProperties.set("Object_ID", setkeyWord);

    nestedNode.set("properties", innerProperties);
```

But this results:

```
"mappings": {
            "archive": {
                "properties": {
                    "Object_IDs": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Object_ID": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

Please help me in creating `mapping` for [nested field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) using  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper. But you can create your index by mapping the Object_IDs field to nested type like  below.

```
"Object_IDs":{  
       "type":"nested",
       "properties":{  
          "Object_ID": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```